# Single quote marks in text breaking javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to know how to allow users to have single quote marks inside their text and other symbols without breaking the javascript code. Right now if a user write a title that says for example " I wouldn't" it will break the javascript code.

```
 <a class="delete_post" href="javascript:delpost('<?php echo $row['id']; ?>','<?php echo $row['postTitle']; ?>')">Delete post</a>


function delpost(id, title) {
  if (confirm("Are you sure you want to delete '" + title + "'")) {
    window.location.href = '../../backend/posts/delete-post.php?delpost=' + id;
  }
}
```

Comment: Before quote write \ means back slash

Comment: Can you elaborate on "it will break the javascript code" ? Are there any errors specifically?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two steps to this.

1. Turn a PHP string into a JavaScript string literal
2. Make the JavaScript string literal safe for inserting into HTML

`json_encode` will deal with the first one (JSON is a data format that is more-or-less a subset of JavaScript). Note that it will add the quote marks needed to make it a JS string literal.

`htmlspecialchars` will handle the other.

```
<a class="delete_post" 
   href="javascript:delpost(<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($row['id'])); ?>,<?php echo htmlspecialchars(json_encode($row['postTitle'])); ?>)">
       Delete post
</a>
```

---

That said…

A nicer way to do this would be to use more apropriate markup.

You aren't **linking** anywhere, so you shouldn't use a link, and you are making the code entirely dependant on JavaScript when you don't need to. Since you are making a significant change on the server (by deleting something) you should use a POST request, not a GET request.

Write unobtrusive JavaScript.

```
<form class="deletepost" action="deletepost" method="post">
    <button>Delete post</button>
    <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['id']);?>">
    <input type="hidden" name="postTitle" value="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($row['postTitle']);?>">
</form>

<script>
    addEventListener("submit", function (event) {
        if (event.target.classList.contains("deletepost")) {
            var elements = event.target.elements;
            if (!confirm("Are you sure you want to delete '" + elements.postTitle.value + "'?")) {
                event.preventDefault();
            }
        }
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you, this looks like a much better way to do it. Thanks for explaining my mistakes and etc.. One problem with your code, It all works to delete the posts but the javascript doesn't work and i get the error " Cannot read property 'elements' of undefined.

Comment: Ooops, didn't think that trouble. It should be just `event.target.elements`.

Answer (score 0):

You can always use template literal syntax instead of string concatenation.

```
confirm(`Are you sure you want to delete '${title}'`)
```

Note that this is an ES6 feature. You need a transpiler like babel to make it compatible across all browsers.

Comment: You should also note template literals are ES6 and also not supported in IE11 https://caniuse.com/#search=template%20literals

Comment: @Quentin can you create a reproduceable sample? I tried it out myself and I don't see  any issues

Comment: I spoke too soon. This won't solve the problem because it doesn't address the generation of the JavaScript string literals with PHP.

Answer (score -1):

If you want to do this in javascript to create a valid string you can use encodeURI()

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_encodeuri.asp

If you have to do it in PHP there is also a function for it

http://php.net/manual/fr/function.htmlspecialchars.php

Comment: The escape function is deprecated and should not be used.

Comment: Oh, I didn't see that, I'll edit my answer, thank you